# Verificar checkbox ativo React

Tags: react

Olá, estou precisando verificar se um ou mais checkbox esta ou estão marcados, para submeter o formulário. O formulário só pode ser submetido se um ou mais checkbox estiverem marcado(s).

Segue meu código:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import Button from '../../components/button/Button'
import './Professor.css'

const professores = [
  {
    id: 1,
    nome: 'Marco Castro',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nome: 'Maike Brito',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    nome: 'Loiane Groner',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    nome: 'Vinicius Dacal',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    nome: 'Leonardo Moura',
  },
]

const turmas = [
  {
    id: 1,
    turma: 'Matutino',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    turma: 'Vespertino',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    turma: 'Noturno',
  },
]

function Professor() {
  const [infoProf, setInfoProf] = useState('')
  const [infoTurma, setInfoTurma] = useState({})
  const [values, setValues] = useState([])

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    if (!infoProf.trim()) {
      return alert('Obrigatório a escolha de um professor!')
    }

    // const teste = values.map((item) => item.turma)

    console.log(infoTurma)
    setValues([...values, { nome: infoProf, turma: infoTurma }])

    clearChange()
  }

  function clearChange() {
    setInfoProf('')
    setInfoTurma('')
  }

  return (
    <div className="form-professor">
      <h1>Cadastro de Professores</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="" className="label-professor">
          Professor
        </label>
        <select
          className="select-professor"
          value={infoProf}
          onChange={(e) => setInfoProf(e.target.value)}
          data-testid="select-professor"
        >
          <option value="0">Selecione um Professor</option>
          {professores.map((professor) => (
            <option
              value={professor.nome}
              key={professor.id}
              data-testid="option-professor"
            >
              {professor.nome}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <div className="check-grup">
          <h2>Slecione quais Turmas</h2>
          {turmas.map((item) => (
            <div
              className="checkbox-professor"
              key={item.id}
              data-testid="checkbox_id"
            >
              <input
                name={item.turma}
                id={item.turma}
                type="checkbox"
                checked={infoTurma[item.turma] || false}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setInfoTurma({
                    ...infoTurma,
                    [e.target.name]: e.target.checked,
                  })
                }
              />
              <label htmlFor={item.turma}>{item.turma}</label>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>

        <Button text="Enviar" />
      </form>

      <div className="list-containerProfessor">
        <ul className="list-cardsProfessor">
          {values.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={index} data-testid="todo-listProfessor">
              <div className="list-turmaProfessor">
                <p>{item.nome}</p>
                <p>{Object.keys(item.turma).join(', ')}</p>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Professor
```

Comment: viu a resposta deu certo para você?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tinha alguns erros e dados desconectados entre as informações base com aquelas que estavam no formulário e isso é ruim, porque, o dado a ser enviado é diferente do estado natural do componente.

Foi criado um segundo estado para armazenar as turmas escolhidas, que no método `onChange` desses `checkbox` tem que verificar se é adição ou remoção e com isso se a quantidade for maior do que zero você pode submeter esse formulário.

Um outra observação quando se passa a informação de um estado precisa usar um nova cópia (por ser um `array` que é um tipo por referencia) para não ser apagado logo após a sua adição no estado `values`.

O exemplo logo abaixo demonstra isso:

```js
const professores = [
  {
    id: 1,
    nome: 'Marco Castro',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nome: 'Maike Brito',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    nome: 'Loiane Groner',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    nome: 'Vinicius Dacal',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    nome: 'Leonardo Moura',
  },
]

const turmas = [
  {
    id: 1,
    turma: 'Matutino',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    turma: 'Vespertino',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    turma: 'Noturno',
  },
]

function Professor() {
  const [infoProf, setInfoProf] = React.useState('');
  const [infoTurma, setInfoTurma] = React.useState([]);
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState([]);  
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (!infoProf.trim()) {
      alert('Obrigatório a escolha de um professor!');
      return;
    }    
    if (infoTurma.length === 0) {
      alert('Obrigatório a escolha da turmas!');
      return;
    }
    setValues([...values, { nome: infoProf, turma: [...infoTurma ]}]);
    clearChange()
  }

  function clearChange() {
    setInfoProf('')
    setInfoTurma([])
  }

  return (
    <div className="form-professor">
      <h1>Cadastro de Professores</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="" className="label-professor">
          Professor
        </label>
        <select
          className="select-professor"
          value={infoProf}
          onChange={(e) => setInfoProf(e.target.value)}
          data-testid="select-professor"
        >
          <option value="0">Selecione um Professor</option>
          {professores.map((professor) => (
            <option
              value={professor.nome}
              key={professor.id}
              data-testid="option-professor"
            >
              {professor.nome}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <div className="check-grup">
          <h2>Selecione quais Turmas</h2>
          {turmas.map((item) => (
            <div
              className="checkbox-professor"
              key={item.id}
              data-testid="checkbox_id"
            >
              <input
                name={item.turma}
                id={item.turma}
                type="checkbox"
                checked={infoTurma.includes(item.turma)}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  if (e.target.checked) { // add
                    setInfoTurma([
                      ...infoTurma,
                      e.target.name
                    ]);
                  } else { // delete
                    setInfoTurma(
                      infoTurma.filter(x => 
                        x !== e.target.name                      
                      )
                    )
                  }                  
                }}
              />
              <label htmlFor={item.turma}>{item.turma}</label>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>

        <button>Enviar</button>
      </form>

      <div className="list-containerProfessor">
        <ul className="list-cardsProfessor">
          {values.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={index} data-testid="todo-listProfessor">
              <div className="list-turmaProfessor">
                <p>{item.nome}</p>
                <p>{Object.keys(item.turma).join(', ')}</p>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <Professor/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">...</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @novic, deu certo aqui. Vlw mesmo, abraços;

Comment: se for útil assinale como resposta! @EmersonMoreira